# .htaccess Redirect 301 with ? (without variables)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

There are some urls with ?.

```
/shop/index.php?route=affiliate/register

/shop/?route=affiliate/register
```

It is needed for these urls to be redirected to:

```
/another-page/
```

(asume all urls begin with the home directory. example: www.homepage.com/shop?route=affiliate/register )

I have tried both simple apache Redirect 301 and rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule as your top rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /shop/(?:index\.php)?\?route=[^\s&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /another-page/? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice command sir could you please do lemme know how could I test this in my local system? Is there curl command or in browser? Will be grateful if you could guide here sir

Comment: I setup using command line curl. I have a local Apache+php running using LAMP/MAMP stack.